# 'Linking CXX executable worldserver' fails

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, jemalloc, azerothcore

Linking CXX executable worldserver at 99% compiling after cmake already pre-compiled fails.

```
[ 99%] Linking CXX executable worldserver
/usr/bin/ld: ../../../deps/jemalloc/libjemalloc.a(jemalloc.c.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `sz_size2index_tab' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: ../../../deps/jemalloc/libjemalloc.a(large.c.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `sz_size2index_tab' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
```

etc.

The error is: https://pastebin.com/pVEkzzNs

I'm running the latest Ubuntu and trying to install the latest AzerothCore per SSH (no auto-installer).

Expected: Everything should work well.
Actual: The binaries don't even get created.

Comment: what are your compiler name and version?

Comment: In the CMakeLists.txt file, is there any obvious way of setting compile flags that includes '-fPIC'?

Comment: Is `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` set?

Comment: @FrancescoBorzi I currently used the `sudo apt-get install git cmake make gcc g++ clang libmysqlclient-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libncurses-dev mysql-server libace-6.* libace-dev` @Barbz_YHOOL I set the `DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, yea.

Comment: can you post the output of your cmake?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DjhSZy4r

Comment: https://pastebin.com/x02SfmDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `relocation R_X86_64_32S ... can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC` indicates that most likely, the project includes precompiled libraries for `libjemalloc.a` which are not compiled as PIC code.  Since Ubuntu has recently switched to compiling Position Independent Executables by default, with the default toolchain settings all objects which go into an executable must be compiled in PIC mode.

I would probably get in touch with the maintainer(s) of the project you are trying to build, and notify them of this compatibility issue.  In the meantime, you might be able to work around this issue by setting `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` to `-no-pie` (e.g. edit the variable in `ccmake` or `cmake-gui` - you will probably have to enable display of "advanced variables" - or specify it on a cmake command line using something like `cmake /path/to/source -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-no-pie`).  Note that this does decrease security of the resulting executable somewhat, as then the kernel will not be able to apply address space randomization to the base executable.

Comment: I've just updated my Ubuntu, restarted my machine and tried to clean compile the whole project again. I couldn't reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering if you set the correct path.

I see your using root? To compile for user.

```
root@core /home/users/tide/wow/source/build # cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/users/tide/wow/server -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILERT=/usr/bin/clang++ -DTOOLS=0 -DWITH_WARNINGS=1 -DSCRIPTS=1
```

Just wondering are you sure path is not this below.

````
root@core /home/tide/wow/source/build # cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/tide/wow/server -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILERT=/usr/bin/clang++ -DTOOLS=0 -DWITH_WARNINGS=1 -DSCRIPTS=1```
````